# Missing slash between base url and all links

Tags: magento

I have a really irritating problem with my magento installation. I have a magento(1.4.x) installed under `www.domain.com` address. I've cloned it to `/beta/` directory to make an upgrade on test environment and also cloned database but i'm not able to resolve one simple-looking problem.

Every link on my test installation is missing a slash between `base url` and 'the rest' of URL so, for example, if magento tries to include a js file, URL to this file is rendered like this: `www.domain.com/betajs/filetoinclude.js`
instead of
`www.domain.com/beta/js/filetoinclude.js`.

I have edited URLs of my test environment in database, cleared cache and done all the other things poeople were suggesting on bulletin boards but i'm still missing this slash.

This problem is descibed a bit wider here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/234373

Have you any idea what can i do to make it working ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the URLs you edited in the database have a trailing slash?

Comment: nope. I have probably reinstalled it from scratch in beta folder

Comment: Facing same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Recently i faced such problem.After deleting cache folder solve the issue.You can try either delete from cpanel or ftp or use below commands to remove cache.

Clear Cache and Temporaly files:

```
rm -rf downloader/pearlib/cache/*
rm -rf downloader/pearlib/download/*
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/session/*
rm -rf var/report/*
rm -rf var/tmp/*
```

Additionally, if your catalog has changed over time, you may want to clean all image cache files.

```
rm -rf media/catalog/product/cache/*
rm -rf media/tmp/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your admin panel > system > configuration > general > web > unsecure and make sure **Base URL** is http://www.domain.com/beta**/** (notice: slash at the end of link)
Do the same with system > configuration > general > web > **secure**

Hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: nope, first thing is that i can't save admin panel forms cause the admin panel is also broken in the same way and i'm not able to send the forms. Second thing is that i've set those two variables through phpMyAdmin (with the ending slash). It's still not working.

Comment: Did you clear magento cache in {magento-root-directory}/var? It would better if you delete the **var** folder

Answer (score 0):

In your system configuration in the Admin, make sure that you change your Store View under the `Current Configuration Scope` on the top left.  Change to each option in that dropdown and check your `Web` settings for Unsecure and Secure URL settings.  Chances are one of these is missing a trailing slash.