# How do i fix these wrong URL's in my broken magento deployment?

Tags: magento, url, deployment, stylesheet

This is my first attempt at using Magento to develop a site. I have to admit the learning curve has been steep, but i have been able to navigate most of the challenges thus far. Here at the final hurdle, however, i have stumbled.

**Specs:**

---

> - Magento 1.7.0.2
> - Apache version 2.2.22
> - PHP version 5.3.10
> - MySQL version 5.1.65-cll

Magento is located in a folder on the server named *magento* one directory down, as in *http://www.mydomain.co.za/magento*

**Problem:**

---

No images are displayed in the front end or backend. It is as if it cannot access the stylesheets. When viewing the source, i can see that the paths are wrong. It searches for the stylesheets in *http://www.mydomain.co.za/* and not in the *magento* folder. I can access the backend by typing in *http://www.mydomain.co.za/magento/index.php/admin* and that brings up the backend without any styling. After that however, every request results in 404. The URL looks like *http://www.mydomain.co.za/magento/adminindex.php* without a slash between admin and index. Introducing that slash manually after every 404 results in correct page being displayed (still without styling). So clearly the problem is here, but i can't seem to fix it. And YES, i do have the slash after the path in the database for both secure and unsecure.

**Attempts to solve:**

---

- Changed the url’s in database [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762090/how-do-i-transfer-a-local-magento-install-onto-my-live-server)
- Changed app/etc/local.xml to use correct database
- Changed .htaccess to include this line: RewriteBase /magento/ (but i
  removed it again)
- Deleted the appropriate cache and sessions folders
- Tried some of the suggestion given here [link](http://www.kudoswebsolutions.com/web-design-blog/magento-deployment-tips)

Now, i am stuck. I have worked my way through error upon error (no fault of Magento, just the learning curve) and i am tired… :-( If someone can please give me some advice as to what to try next, it would be greatly appreciated.

I found these links of the (seemingly) similar problem. Clearly there is something happening here. The other thread never solved the issued, just found a work around. Is it possible that we have run into a bug? Something is stripping that slash out and it isn’t any of the usual suspects… *dum dum dum*

[link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/234373/)
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220988/missing-slash-between-base-url-and-all-links)

Comment: What url do you have in Admin -> Config -> General -> Web -> Unsecure -> Base url ?

Comment: http:// www. mydomain.co.za/magento/ -- obviously this not actually my domain :-P

Comment: I got a work-around to this problem, but was unable to solve it. I kept the database and did a fresh install of magento on the live server. This somehow resolved the issue. There seems to be a problem with moving magento up or down the directory tree. This might just be in cases where the move coincides with a move from one environment to another. This problem persistes even though the correct paths are supplied. Clearly it is "hard-coded" somewhere from the installation settings and then not re-read from the database.